# Advice on how to store/manage files for entries in DB

Tags: php, mysql, file, web, storage

I have made a database with tables like **projects**, **employees**.
I have some fotos and pdf files (for instance, scan of certificates) related to the entries in my DB, that should be accessible via our internal web site.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should manage this?

I was thinking on setting up a subdomain "files.ourdomain.com", and create subdirectories there for each table. And make a directory for each record? Should i create a DB field for "employee.certificates" with the entire path/filename of the certificate foto?`

Or should i actually store the files in the database? (MySql INNODB)

Comment: For security reasons it's better and easier if you will store it in database

Comment: Well, security is not really top priority - there's not really any sensitive data.

Also, this is a small company, max a few users at the same time so performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, Peter said that it's easier and better to store the files in a database for security reasons and there is a case for this - only DBA's and the webservers will have access to the files and they could be encrypted. I don't agree with the "easier" bit though as  you would need to encode the image before placing it into the DB and decode again when you want to display it.

You have a choice:

1. you store the files actually in the database itself
2. you store the file in a folder (outside of the web tree) and only store the
   filename to the file

Each method has pros and cons:

If you store the files actually within the database you could take the backup file and put it onto another server and everything will be present. However, if you're using replication or clustering then each server will have a copy of the file and so storage requirements increase. Obvious, you will also need more space for backups, and backing up and restoration will take proportionally longer.

If you store the file in a central location and only record the location, your DB storage requirements are lower and multiple DB servers can be confident that there is only ever one copy of a file. Again, the files can be backed up separately. The downside is "what happens if your file storage server fails". However, with mirroring and backups, this can be mitigated against.

In both cases, you would need to store a filename for each file so that the webservers can use them.

Have a look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database) which does a much better job of the pros and cons than I ever could.

Speaking personally, I store a filename which links to an external file.

Comment: Thanks, I've decided that I will not store the files in DB. I still would like opinions on how to organize everything though, like filename/folder structure etc.

Comment: Use a subfolder for each user ID. within each folder, you can have separate folders for each file type if you like - it's a matter of personal choice. One thing I would recommend is to adjust the filename so that there is a timestamp (e.g., `cert.pdf` is renamed to `cert_20141405115425.pdf`). This will allow you to have multiple (e.g.) certificates and make the filenames easily adjustable for download to a client machine (if required). Don't make the file store server publicly accessible (i.e., from the web) - Web & DB servers only